# Using a matrix to answer Ax=b question

Tags: linear-algebra

Use Matrix $A$ to answer the following.

This is matrix  $A$

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0&  3 \\
-1&-1& -1&   1 \\
0&  -4&   2&   -8 \\
2 &0 & 3& -1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Turning into echelon form I get
 $A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0&  3 \\
0& 2& -1&  4 \\
0&  0&   0&   5 \\
0& 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

I am having a tough time answering these question

**1. How many rows of $A$ contain a pivot?** My answer $3$

**2. Does the equation $Ax=b$ have a solution for each $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$?**

My answer: no because my last row is all zero unless the last entry in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is zero.

**3. Can each vector be written as a linear combination of the columns of the matrix $A$ above?**

**4. Do the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^4$?**

I am not sure about the last two.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Do you know the definition of "span" and "linear combination"?

Comment: No it is not homework. I am just practicing from my text book and I am stuck on this problem. Span I think is when, basically you have a matrix A and you are asking if b is in its span so you set up a linear system and solve it in algebra. But geometrically it means if two vectors are in same plane or line.

Comment: Linear combination I think is when you have a matrix say A and you have column is it 2,3,2 and your first entry in a vector is say 3. So you do 2x3,3x3,3x2. Something like that I think.

Comment: Looking at my linear algebra book apparently if it has a pivot position in every row, then it the matrix spans R^N.  So it does not spawn R^4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't solve the problems for you, because you already have the solutions to the last two problems: they are merely rewording of the previous parts. Instead I will try to help you understand the meaning of these two concepts better: span, and linear combinations.

- **Linear combination:** any vector of the form $c_1+\dots+c_kv_k$ is called a linear combination of $v_1, \dots, v_k$. Here $c_i$ are numbers.
- **Span:** Span of a set of vectors $v_1, \dots, v_k$ is the set of all of their linear combinations; that is to say, $\mathrm{Span}\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}=\{c_1v_1+\dots+c_kv_k\ \text{ for all real (or complex) numbers } c_i\}$.

Now let's look at part $4$ for instance. Columns of $A$ are $4$ vectors, say $A_1, \dots, A_4$, in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The question is asking whether 
$$\mathrm{Span}\{A_1, \dots, A_4\}=\mathbb{R}^4.$$
That is to say, whether any $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be written as 
$$x_1A_1+\dots+x_4A_4=b.$$
But this is equivalent to asking whether the system $Ax=b$ is solvable for **all** choices of $b$, a question that you have already answered.